# Am I able to take a train from Moscow, Russia directly to Kiev, Ukraine given the current political situation?

Tags: trains, russia, ukraine, moscow, kyiv

I am planning on travelling from Russia to Ukraine in `2017` via train and was curious if taking a direct train was still an option. I am aware of the Belarussian route but would prefer to not deal with the paperwork.

Comment: My train to Lviv theoretically continued to Moscow, but it may have gone through Belarus. I don't know more than this since I am unable to visit either due to lack of visas.

Comment: Are you asking if such a train exists or if you can take as a foreigner?

Comment: @GayotFow Both Russian and Ukrainian Railways list 6-7 daily direct trains between Moscow and Kiev. On the Russian Railways website, you can even book tickets for these trains online and I find no information that they are not open for Russian citizens. Where do you have your information from that there are no trains, or that any running trains are not open to Russians?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo helping my niece book one from Peter to Simferopol via Kyiv last summer and couldn't do it, but the answer makes it clear it's possible now.  Soz :)

Comment: @GayotFow, Simferopol is not the same as mainland Ukraine. Feel the difference :)

Comment: @Suncatcher I'm heading back in a few weeks and will make a point of feeling it, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @GayotFow, BTW how did you get to Crimea via Kyiv? Did you use Novoalekseevka for change? Also, special permit is required for foreigners. Have you received it smoothly?

Comment: @Suncatcher We're not foreigners, but my niece ended up flying and driving, skipping Kyiv, for totally unrelated reasons.

Comment: @GayotFow, the question is about Kiev, not about the Crimea. To get there by train, you can't use ukranian trains

Comment: @VMAtm consider adding a new answer to the question I posted when I was planning http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69295/border-controls-between-krasnodar-and-the-crimea

Comment: You've asked about the car, not the train :) I can't add something useful for that answers there.

Answer (score 6):

**If you're Russian**:
There is no problem to take a train right now, from Kiev to Moscow and vise versa. The problem is to get an ukranian visa, espesially for a men with suitable age for being in army. However, a friend of mine got a working trip to Kiev this year, so the political situation here is bad, but the transport connections still are available, if you are using the surface transport, the flights still cannot be made.
Still, the valid visa does not guarantee the successfull entrance, because of the political situation.

**If you're resident of any other country** you probably never face any troubles if your documents are valid, yet another border control.

Comment: Things are complicated for Russians:) So hardly could be formalized in generic guidelines that would be appropriate for all.

Comment: Is it still safe to travel between Ukraine and Russia by train or bus considering there's an armed conflict going on? I'm Canadian (so can go to Ukraine without visa) and I have a valid Russia visa.

Comment: This depends on what border point you're using. I assume that train is much more safe, but you probably can use the plane (with a stop in Minsk or other airport).

Comment: @user1271772 The contested area is [more than 400 km away](https://imgur.com/a/kPjyzD8) from the train's route, your much greater concern should be staying warm in a poorly heated railway car for over 12 hours in winter.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of trains between Moscow and Kiev, you can check them [Russian Railways Passenger Information](https://pass.rzd.ru/timetable/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=735&refererVpId=1&refererPageId=704#dir=0%7Ctfl=3%7CcheckSeats=1%7Cst0=%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%92%D0%90%7Ccode0=2000000%7Cdt0=24.11.2016%7Cst1=%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%95%D0%92%7Ccode1=2200000%7Cdt1=25.11.2016) (if the link out of date, try their [home page](http://rzd.ru)). I didn't hear about real problems vith visas or border-crossing between the Ukrain and Russia, we are just annoyed about the fact we now need to apply for visa, but I can believe it could be some things with getting visa.

Comment: Is it still safe to travel between Ukraine and Russia by train or bus considering there's an armed conflict going on? I'm Canadian (so can go to Ukraine without visa) and I have a valid Russia visa.